# programmatically create VC, Use integers from UItext field in formula and perform a calculation when UIButton is tapped

Tags: uibutton, uitextfield, swift5, programmatically-created

all,  this code does not throw errors now but the screen is blank.  I am trying to create a simple calculator.  user will input numbers into 3 separate UIText fields, push a button and a UILabel would give answer.  I know i do not have labels yet.  i first built a container to hold text fields but then my "CalculateTapped" could not see the textFields as variables.

Question. 1 why is my screen now black?
Question. 2. why could i not get CalculateTapped to read UIText fields from my lazy var "" view earlier?

If anyone has any input i would greatly appreciate it.  trying to get away from storyboards.

import UIKit

```
class PitchLineVC: UIViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        let view = UIView()
            ()
            view.backgroundColor = .white
            view.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor,bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor);
            configureNavigationBar()

    //        looks for keyboard instance
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PitchLineVC.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PitchLineVC.keyboarWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        }

    //   keeps screen from rotating
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
            return false
    }  

//  Add text fields for user input to calculate pitch
    private lazy var areaTxt: UITextField! = {
    let area = UITextField()

    area.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
    area.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -300).isActive = true
    area.placeholder = "Bar Area"
    area.textAlignment = .center
    area.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
    area.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    area.textColor = UIColor.black
    area.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
//    view.addSubview(area)
        return(area)
    }()
        private lazy var areaTop: UITextField! = {
        let area = UITextField()

        area.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        area.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -200).isActive = true
        area.placeholder = "Top Area of Bar"
        area.textAlignment = .center
        area.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
        area.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        area.textColor = UIColor.black
        area.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
//        view.addSubview(area)
            return(area)
    }()

        private lazy var lineLength: UITextField! = {
            let line = UITextField()

            line.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
            line.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -300).isActive = true

//            line.anchor(top: view.bottomAnchor, paddingTop: -80,width: 100, height: 35)
            line.placeholder = "Line Length"
            line.textAlignment = .center
            line.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
            line.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            line.textColor = UIColor.black
            line.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
//            view.addSubview(line)
            return (line)
        }()


    @objc func CalculateTapped(){
                       print("Button Tapped")
            let AreaTotal = Double(areaTxt.text!)
                let AreaTop = Double(areaTop.text!)
                let Line = Double(lineLength.text!)

                if AreaTotal != nil && AreaTop != nil && Line != nil{

                    let LineMove = -(((AreaTotal! / 2) - AreaTop!) / Line!)

                    movepitchline.text = NSString(format: "%.3f", LineMove) as String
                }

                   }

            func addCalculateButton(){
                   let Calculate = UIButton()

                    Calculate.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CalculateTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                    Calculate.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
                    Calculate.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -400).isActive = true
                    Calculate.anchor(top: view.bottomAnchor, paddingTop: -80,
                                           width: 100, height: 35)
                view.addSubview(Calculate)

                   }

    let movepitchline: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .right
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 380, width: 220, height: 35)
        label.text = "Move Pitch:"
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 23)
        label.textColor = .black
        return label
    }()


//    When keyboard displays the UIView shift up
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
           // if keyboard size is not available for some reason, dont do anything
           return
        }
      // move the root view up by the distance of keyboard height
      self.view.frame.origin.y = 150 - keyboardSize.height
    }

    @objc func keyboarWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0//\\100 + keyboardSize.height
    }

//    select outside text box to dismiss selection
    @objc func handleDismiss(notification: NSNotification) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func configureNavigationBar() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .appBlue
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black

        navigationItem.title = "Pass Pitch and Diameters"
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Home_2x").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss))

    }

}
```

Comment: fixed it and also added some other features such as keyboard dismissing, using numerical keypad.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class PitchLineVC: UIViewController {


    lazy var pitchlogoView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PITCH LINE")
        return iv
    }()

    lazy var areaTxt: UITextField! = {
        let tf = UITextField()

        tf.placeholder = "Bar Area"
        tf.textAlignment = .center
        tf.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
        tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        tf.textColor = UIColor.black
        tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
            return(tf)
        }()

    lazy var areaTop: UITextField! = {
            let tf = UITextField()

            tf.placeholder = "Top Area of Bar"
            tf.textAlignment = .center
            tf.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
            tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            tf.textColor = UIColor.black
            tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
                return(tf)
        }()

    lazy var lineLength: UITextField! = {
                let tf = UITextField()

                tf.placeholder = "Line Length"
                tf.textAlignment = .center
                tf.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
                tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                tf.textColor = UIColor.black
                tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
                return (tf)
            }()

    lazy var movepitchline1: UILabel = {
               let lb = UILabel()
               lb.textAlignment = .right
               lb.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 380, width: 220, height: 35)
               lb.text = "Move Pitch: + is up, - is down"
               lb.textAlignment = .center
               lb.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 23)
               lb.textColor = .black
               return (lb)
           }()

    lazy var movepitchline: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.textAlignment = .right
        lb.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 380, width: 220, height: 35)
        lb.text = ""
        lb.textAlignment = .center

        lb.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 23)
        lb.textColor = .black
        return (lb)
    }()


    let calculateButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 48/255, green: 173/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        button.tintColor = UIColor.white
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 6
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        button.setTitle("Calculate", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Copperplate", size: 22)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCalculate), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    @objc func handleDismiss(notification: NSNotification) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //sets trigger for keyboard dismiss
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }

//    Mark: Init
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        configureNavigationBar()
        configureViewComponent()

    //        looks for keyboard instance
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PitchLineVC.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PitchLineVC.keyboarWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        }

    //   keeps screen from rotating
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
            return false
    }

//    Mark: Selectors


    @objc func handleCalculate()
    {
        print("calculate")
        guard let AreaTotal = Double(areaTxt.text!) else {return}
        guard let AreaTop = Double(areaTop.text!) else {return}
        guard let Line = Double(lineLength.text!) else {return}


        if AreaTotal != 0 && AreaTop != 0 && Line != 0{

            let LineMove = -(((AreaTotal / 2) - AreaTop) / Line)
            print(LineMove)
            movepitchline.text = NSString(format: "%.3f", LineMove) as String

        } else{
            print("Error in fields, please check entry")
        }

    }

    func configureViewComponent(){
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(pitchlogoView)
        pitchlogoView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 120, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 250, height: 110)

        view.addSubview(areaTxt)
        areaTxt.anchor(top: pitchlogoView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 15, paddingLeft: 80, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 80, width: 0, height: 30)

        view.addSubview(areaTop)
        areaTop.anchor(top: areaTxt.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 80, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 80, width: 0, height: 30)

        view.addSubview(lineLength)
        lineLength.anchor(top: areaTop.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 80, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 80, width: 0, height: 30)

        view.addSubview(calculateButton)
        calculateButton.anchor(top: lineLength.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 30, paddingLeft: 32, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 32, width: 0, height: 50)

        view.addSubview(movepitchline1)
        movepitchline1.anchor(top: calculateButton.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 32, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 32, width: 0, height: 40)

        view.addSubview(movepitchline)
        movepitchline.anchor(top: movepitchline1.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 32, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 32, width: 0, height: 40)
        }

//    When keyboard displays the UIView shift up
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
           // if keyboard size is not available for some reason, dont do anything
           return
        }
      // move the root view up by the distance of keyboard height

      self.view.frame.origin.y = 165 - keyboardSize.height
    }

    @objc func keyboarWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }

//    select outside text box to dismiss selection

    func configureNavigationBar() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .appBlue
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black

        navigationItem.title = "Pass Pitch and Diameters"
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Home_2x").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss))

    }

}
```